# Query String with native query and ordered parameter, sql doesn't work

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-el

I have the following code

```
  @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select  e.* from event e"
  + " join league  l on (l.id = e.league_id)"
  + " join sport s on (l.sport_id = s.id)"
  + " join team t1 on (t1.id = e.team_one_id)"
  + " join team t2 on (t2.id = e.team_two_id)"
  + " join country c on (c.id = l.country_id)"
  + " where l.name LIKE %?1%")

Page<Event> getAllEventsFiltered(final PageRequest of, final String filter);
```

If execute this SQL into database I receive a lot of results but when is executed from java I receive no one result in the same SQL.

I already tried:

```
where l.name LIKE %?#{escape([1])} escape ?#{escapeCharacter()}
```

but just works to begins and I needs for both begin and end.

Comment: Which database are you using  ?

Answer (score 0):

JDBC parameters can only be included in very specific places in a SQL statement. They are not *replaced* as strings in the SQL statement but they are *applied*. The specific valid places change from database to database, and also depend on the JDBC driver variant/version.

The general rule is that a parameter can be applied where a single value would be present. String parameters should not be enclosed in single quotes as a `VARCHAR` would be.

One option to make it compliant, is to place the parameter isolated from other text, for example by using the `CONCAT()` function. Your query could be rephrased as:

```
  @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select  e.* from event e"
  + " join league  l on (l.id = e.league_id)"
  + " join sport s on (l.sport_id = s.id)"
  + " join team t1 on (t1.id = e.team_one_id)"
  + " join team t2 on (t2.id = e.team_two_id)"
  + " join country c on (c.id = l.country_id)"
  + " where l.name LIKE concat('%', ?1, '%')") // change here
```

Nevertheless, the specific syntax change can be different depending on the database you are using (that you haven't mentioned).